# Script to copy files from Nikon D60 Digital camera to WAMP server?

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am nearly done my photobooth app, but I need to be able to access files from a Nikon D60 with WAMP. At the very least I need a program that will copy new photos from the camera and place them in a directory on an interval. Anyone ever work with something like this before?

Comment: Is the camera assigned a drive letter?

Comment: WAMP & PHP may be configured so that it cannot see anything outside its own directories.  If that is not the case - or you change things to allow access - then you should be able to use [PHP's filesystem functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) to access the camera; however, a detailed explanation of this is beyond the scope of what you'll get in an answer here.  All that said, I'd really recommend copying the files to a subdirectory of the WAMP documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which drive letter your Nikon will be assigned, you should have an idea of the hierarchy of your camera drive. I know when I plug my digital camera I will have a DCIM folder, and inside I have my pictures. You can either browse through all the drives looking for a hierarchy that matched that of your Nikon or code the drive the camera is "usually" assigned.

In terms of copying the content, you can try using the [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) command; big gotchas with most of the file structure commands deal with permissions issue, make sure the user running the php command has access to whatever folders you will be accessing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a small program from http://www.diyphotobits.com/ to copy files into a directory on my WAMP server. I then used a script with GLOB to collect all the files in the directory, process them, then make an XML manifest that was accessible to frontend systems.